# лексикографический порядок

Tags: функциональное-программирование

Вообще не понимаю что это...
Расположить следующие строки битов в лексикографическом порядке: 0, 01, 11, 001, 010, 011, 0001, 0101, считая, что  0<1.

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Слова в бумажном словаре расположены в лексикографическом порядке. Строки из цифр - те же слова. Их можно упорядочить по алфавиту.

Comment: Показанный пример непохож на лексикографический порядок, данные строки сначала сравниваются по длине, а уже группы с равной длиной сортируются в _обычном_ порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Лексикографический порядок** (dictionary order, lexicographical order) — отношение линейного порядка на множестве слов над некоторым упорядоченным алфавитом.

**Примеры:**

- естественный порядок на неотрицательных целых числах в любой позиционной системе счисления, записанных в разрядной сетке фиксированной длины (000, 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, …, 998, 999)
- порядок слов в словаре. Предполагается, что буквы можно сравнивать, сравнивая их номера в алфавите. Тогда лексикографический порядок — это, например, А < АА < ААА < ААБ < ААВ < АБ < Б < … < ЯЯЯ.

**Инструкция:**

- В основе лексикографического порядка лежит алфавит. Слова, начинающиеся на букву «а», предшествуют словам, начинающимся на букву «б». Слова, начинающиеся на «ан», идут раньше слов, начинающихся на «ар», и так далее.
  При сортировке учитываются все буквы.
- Если все буквы более короткого слова совпадают с началом более длинного слова, то короткое слово предшествует длинному. Например, слово «бар» идет раньше, чем «бармен».

**Текущая задача:**

для вас соответственно -

- сначала слова у которых первый символ 0
- затем слова у которых первый символ 1
- дальше берем все слова с первым символом 0 и сортируем их по 2 символу
- ... по 3 символу и т.д.
- ... аналогично для слов с первым символом 1

**К примеру**

```
10 1 00 0 01 11
```

на 0 начинаются

```
00
0
01
```

на 1 начинаются

```
10
1
11
```

по 2 правилу инструкции:

```
0 00 01

1 10 11
```

Пример 2:

допустим есть следующие числа `0000001, 0010, 0`

Будет так:

шаг1:

```
0 - потому что самое короткое число
0[000001 или 010] - осталось отсортировать 2 других
```

шаг 2:

```
0
00[00001 или 10] - 2 цифра у них также одинаковая, надо смотреть 3 цифру
```

шаг 3:

```
0
0000001 - потому что 3 цифра 0 - она меньше 1
0010 - потому что 3 цифра 1 - она больше 0
```